# How to remove everything Ubuntu One-related?

Tags: ubuntu-one, aptitude, uninstall

Is `sudo aptitude purge ubuntuone?` sufficient to remove everything Ubuntu One-related from my system?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

this guide is great :

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/22881/remove-ubuntu-one-from-ubuntu-10.04/

Comment: Is this linked guide good for 11.10 and 11.04 too, or is there something different that needs to be done?